GeoJSON Problems - UK Parliamentary Constituencies
I want to plot the new parliamentary boundaries for the upcoming general election.
This will use an NIHR API to grab the map location of the FID=3, the 3rd parliamentary constituency in alphabetical order - Altrincham and Sale West.
response = 
 URLExecute[
  "https://nihr.opendatasoft.com/api/explore/v2.1/catalog/datasets/\
westminster-parliamentary-constituencies/records?where=fid%3D3&limit=\
20", "JSON"]

coordinates = response[[2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]] (* these are the coordinates in the JSON, surely there is a better way to grab this? *) 


GeoListPlot[coordinates[[2, 1]]]

When I go to plot this - it doesn't fail, just plots the world. It seems to be a GeoJSON, and when I go to plot this - it says I cannot import the GeoJSON.


You need to fix a few things here:

I'd use GeoGraphics not GeoListPlot. If you insist on GeoListPlot use something like:
 GeoListPlot[Polygon[Reverse /@ coordinates[[2, 1]]]]
 GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[Reverse /@ coordinates[[2, 1]]]]


GeoPolygon[...] - You need a graphics primitive to show up on the map -- coordinates by itself do nothing inside GeoGraphics

Reverse - Longitude and Latitude can get reversed in some data formats and systems, like in this case. So I flipped them.


Result after these fixes:
GeoGraphics[{
 EdgeForm[Directive[Red, Thick]], 
 GeoPolygon[Reverse /@ coordinates[[2, 1]]]},
ImageSize -> 1000]


Use GeoBackground for different stylings:

